# Once I've run `git push` and gone to the page on bitbucket where it asks to create a pull request, what happens if I just don't do it?

Tags: git

So I ran `git push` and when I went to the page on bitbucket to create the pull request, there were two commits there - mine, and someone else's. I only want to push my commit, I have no idea how the other commit got there. So I want to not create this pull request so I can go back and cherry pick my commit on another branch. But I can't figure out how to abort the pull request, or to undo my push.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To "abort the pull request" : just close the browser tab you are in without clicking on the "Create" button.

You can modify your branch as you see fit on your local repo, and then force push your branch to bitbucket (`git push --force-with-lease origin mybranch`).